# Exterior product generates the infinitesimal rotations -- what is the geometric significance?

Tags: lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, exterior-algebra, cross-product, geometric-algebras

> **Question:** What is the geometric significance of the fact that the exterior products of the unit basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ generate a basis for the Lie algebra of the pure rotation group $SO(3)$?
>
> Also, if applicable, what is the algebraic significance or the physical significance?

This is one of the first things I found to be true when investigating all of these subjects, but strangely I have yet to find a single source documenting this phenomenon and explaining its significance. There are no coincidences in mathematics, so seemingly this should have a fairly profound explanation, because otherwise it would be a fairly big coincidence.

My guess is that it means somehow (I'm not sure how) that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the only Euclidean space for which rotations in a plane can be identified with rotations about an axis, since $3-2=1$. In general, rotation about an axis is not defined, while rotation in a plane always is.

Identifying a plane with rotation in the same plane seems like somewhat of a conceptual leap, however. Seemingly the two should be denoted differently somehow.

---

**Context:** Given $\mathbb{R}^n$, in what follows $n=3$.

The infinitesimal rotations are one possible basis for the 3-dimensional vector space of skew-symmetric matrices. This vector space is actually a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ of the Lie group $SO(3)$ of rotation matrices with determinant $1$ (i.e. pure rotations, those which do not contain a reflection).

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  $$

Given the unit basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^3$, $e_1, e_2, e_3$, they have three linearly independent exterior products, $e_1 \wedge e_2, e_2 \wedge e_3,$ and $e_3 \wedge e_1$. Their coordinate representations are familiar:

$$e_1 \wedge e_2 = e_1 \otimes e_2 - e_2 \otimes e_1 =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}  - \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}^T - \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  $$

$$e_2 \wedge e_3 = e_2 \otimes e_3 - e_3 \otimes e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}^T - \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$e_3 \wedge e_1 = e_3 \otimes e_1 - e_1 \otimes e_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}^T - \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

**Other almost certainly related facts:**

- $e_1 \wedge e_2, e_2 \wedge e_3, e_3 \wedge e_1$ are basis $2-$vectors in geometric algebra and hence represent planes. Specifically, $e_1 \wedge e_2$ represents the plane spanned by $e_1$ and $e_2$, $e_2 \wedge e_3$ represents the plane spanned by $e_2$ and $e_3$, and $e_3 \wedge e_1$ represents the plane spanned by $e_3$ and $e_1$.
- If $*$ denotes the Hodge dual, then we have $$(e_1 \wedge e_2)^* = e_1 \times e_2 = e_3$$ $$(e_2 \wedge e_3)^* = e_2 \times e_3 = e_1$$ $$(e_3 \wedge e_1)^* = e_3 \times e_1 = e_2$$ These three equations are just the right hand rule, and represent the facts that:

  - rotation about the $x_3$ axis is the same as rotation in the $x_1,x_2$ plane,
  - rotation about the $x_1$ axis is the same as rotation in the $x_2, x_3$ plane,
  - rotation about the $x_2$ axis is the same as rotation in the $x_3, x_1$ plane.
- Angular momentum is the integral of motion corresponding to rotational invariance, i.e. symmetry with respect to $SO(3)$. (This means, by Noether's theorem, that if the laws of physics are unchanged under pure rotations, then angular momentum is conserved.) Angular momentum also generates the infinitesimal rotations using the Poisson bracket.
- The cross-product algebra on $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be identified with the Lie algebra of pure quaternions (at least when normalizing by a factor of 2). Conjugate multiplication of quaternions can also be used to represent space rotations, leading to an identification of antipodal pairs of unit quaternions with space rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$. (See, for example, section 4.4 or sections 1.4-1.6 of Stillwell's *Naive Lie Theory*.) $2-$vectors in geometric algebra function similarly.

Comment: Why do you focus on $\mathbb R^3$ and $SO(3)$ here? - You seem well aware of quaternions and geometric algebra. Is the connection not clear by considering exponentials of bivectors in the geometric algebra?

Comment: You seem to be right, this procedure should generalize for any $n$. I hadn't realized that before though -- I was caught up with infinitesimal rotations and how they are related to angular momentum via Poisson brackets. My thinking was also that $e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3, \dots$ would be rank-3 tensors thus hard to represent in coordinates, but now I realize that this doesn't make sense as an objection since such things are defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$ also (I guess maybe the interpretation is easier in $\mathbb{R}^3$ because there is only a 1D vector space of 3-vectors? still not sure).

Comment: @Muphrid I am not as familiar with those subjects as you might think -- I did not know that bivectors could be exponentiated or that this was a common operation for them -- I was only familiar with it from Lie algebras/groups and Markov processes (and real/complex numbers obviously). 

Do you have any references discussing the exponentiation of bivectors in geometric algebra?

 I've only read some excerpts of basic introductions to the subject so far - nothing serious.

Comment: Doran and Lasenby cover the correspondence between unit 3d bivectors and pure imaginary quaternions extensively. Dorst, Fontijne, and Mann probably cover things in a more general sense (as they prove extensions to projective geometry). - But in a nutshell, you can prove that $e_1 e_2 \equiv -k$ and similarly for other unit bivectors, and you get the correspondence between bivectors and pure imag. quats. That makes their relationship with rotations clearer.

Comment: In the clifford algebra, we can define the exponential by power series. I don't know if this is what @Muphrid is talking about. $$\exp(v) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{v^i}{i!}= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{\|v\|^{2i}}{(2i)!} + \frac{v \|v\|^{2i}}{(2i+1)!} = \cosh \|v \| + \frac{v}{\|v\|} \sinh \| v \| $$

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, although whether we use trig functions or hyperbolic functions depends on what you're exponentiating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider the exterior algebra $\Lambda^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $\mathfrak{so}(n)$, they are in fact isomorphic as you have hinted at in the above for the case $n=3$.

If you pick $u \wedge v \in \Lambda^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, and then define the linear mapping $\phi(u\wedge v):\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ as:
$$
\phi(u \wedge v)(x) = \left( u \cdot x \right) v - \left( v \cdot x \right) u 
$$
Then we can think of $\phi(u \wedge v) $ as a matrix, which after a little work you can show to be skew-symmetric - so we can say that $\phi(u\wedge v) \in \mathfrak{so}(n)$.

In this sense, we have a mapping $\phi:\Lambda^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \to \mathfrak{so}(n)$. This mapping is in fact an isomorphism between $\Lambda^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $\mathfrak{so}(n)$.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer and method of proof. Just as a follow-up/clarification, the isomorphism is as Lie algebras, correct, and not just as vector spaces?

Comment: This isomorphism applies with any non-degenerate metric on $\mathbb{R^n}$, right?